# Make add method more optimal in Angular with localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

How can I optimize or improve this method from my component in Angular?
I was told that I should use localStorage to get and store the data.

```
addTracks(){
  let itemId = 1;
  if(localStorage.getItem('trackIndex')){
    itemId = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('trackIndex'), 10);

  }
  while(localStorage.getItem(('localPlaylist'.concat(itemId + '')))){
    this.trackList.push((JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(('localPlaylist'.concat(itemId + ''))))));
    itemId--;
  }

}
```

Comment: If you serialise and save the whole `trackList` array as a single item in storage then there is only 1 read/write location to handle

Comment: Can you give me an example? never used that

Comment: `saveTracks() {const tracks = JSON.stringify(this.trackList); window.localStorage.setItem('tracks', tracks);}` and `loadTracks() {const tracks = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('tracks') || '[]'); this.trackList.push(...tracks);}`